# Update an environment variable of an AWS Lambda function in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am wanting to update an Environment Variable from an AWS Lambda function. I have tried this code:

```
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    call = os.environ["last_call"]
    print (call)
    os.environ["last_call"] = "last update now "
    print (os.environ["last_call"])
```

When I reassign the `os.environ["last_call"] = "last update now"`, I don't see the environment variable updating.

I know I am missing something. Could you please guide me how can I update the value every time I call the Lambda function?

Comment: I understand that your question was only about why this won't work, but my first reaction is to ask why would you want to do this? Environment variables are typically values that you pass into a Lambda function that represent some constant. Changing their value can be even dangerous in case same container is re-used for other function invocations. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your objective is to store some information that will be accessible to the Lambda function when the function is next executed.

This can (mostly) be accomplished simply by using a **global variable** rather than an environment variable. Simply define a variable outside of the handler function and it will be accessible during future executions of the function.

However:

- If the function is executed frequently, AWS Lambda might create **multiple containers**. The global variable will only operate within one of the containers, so the value will not be accessible for all functions.
- If a function is not used for some time period, the **container might be destroyed**. This would lose the global variable.

Using an **environment variable** will have the same issues.

The correct way to make information accessible to future executions of a Lambda function would be to use some form of **storage service**, such as DynamoDB, Amazon S3 or a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this... It worked for me.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = client.update_function_configuration(
        FunctionName='my-test-lam-1',
        Environment={
            'Variables': {
                'NAME': 'updated_value',
                'key2': 'val2'
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`os.putenv(key, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.putenv), but with caution:

> **If** the platform supports the `putenv()` function, this mapping may be used to modify the environment as well as query the environment.

Answer (score 0):

environment variables will be used by importing library

```
import os
variable = os.environ["env-variable"]
```